# How to use .hasChild and retrieve child using Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'm working on a project with the following Firebase structure:

```
user {
  score: 0,
  messages : {
    key1 { name: name, text: text }
    key2 { name: name, text: text }
    key...
  }
}
```

I currently have two problems. The first is determining if the user has a "messages" child, if not, then give it one (along with a score), here's the code I came up with so far:

```
  ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasChild("messages")) {
        ref.set({
            score: 0,
            messages: 0
        });
    }
});
```

The next is retrieving and displaying the messages from the child once the data has been pushed to it like so:

```
ref.child("messages").on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    $('#messagesDiv').prepend(message.text ": " + message.name);
});
```

but that doesn't seem like it's working either.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4zgLzs/) I made.

I hope you guys can help me fix this problem! The syntax looks right and I read over the docs to find most of the current code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Setting the initial data

Your code with `hasChild` seems is executed fine. It just doesn't make a lot of sense. The structure that you're adding leads to:

```
user {
  score: 0,
  messages: 0
}
```

Which is not the same as the structure you've drawn in your question: `messages` here is just a number, while you want it to be a collection of messages. In addition this change will **not** trigger your `child_added` handler, since... you're not adding a child to `messages`.

You've done the right thing by starting with designing a data structure. The next step is to ensure that you stick to that data structure. So if you want to add an initial message, add the message in the correct structure:

```
ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasChild("messages")) {
        ref.set({
            score: 0,
            messages: { 0: { name: 'puf', text: 'welcome' }}
        });
    }
});
```

If you modify the fiddle you will see that the `welcome` message does show up in your `#messagesDiv`.

I think this approach is still flawed though. Unless you are really looking to add a welcome message, there is no need to add a `messages` node. I would just set the `score` to 0 and the `messages` node will be added once the user enters their first message:

```
ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasChild("messages")) {
        ref.set({ score: 0 });
    }
});
```

### Adding new messages

I noticed that you also have the following code in your fiddle:

```
$('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var name = user;
        var text = $('#messageInput').val();
        // POST
        ref.child("messages").set({
            name: name,
            text: text
        });
        $('#messageInput').val('');
    }
});
```

The input handling is fine, but once again your code that modifies the Firebase data structure does not follow along with the data structure you started your question with. If we execute this code, the data structure will be:

```
user {
  score: 0,
  messages: {
      name: 'NotToBrag',
      text: 'asked 10 hours ago'
  }
}
```

In case it's not obvious: this structure is missing the *crucial* key1 or your structure. Oh... and it has also overwritten the `welcome` message.

When you're adding a child node to a Firebase list, you almost always want to use `push`:

```
        ref.child("messages").push({
            name: name,
            text: text
        });
```

With that tiny change, the data structure becomes:

```
user {
  score: 0,
  messages: {
      0: {
          name: 'puf',
          text: 'welcome'
      },
      '-Jh-aFN42nWef-FvgcfS': {
          name: 'NotToBrag',
          text: 'asked 10 hours ago'
      }
  }
}
```

All of these are (as usual) pretty small changes. But together they ensured that your scenario was pretty badly broken. The tricks I used to troubleshoot are incredibly basic and you'd do well to add them to your arsenal and learn to use them.

### Debugging trick 1: console.log the data structure

Whenever I first get an MCVE of somebody's problem, I immediately log their data structure:

```
new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) {
  console.log(s.val()); 
})
```

As times I might stringify the JSON:

```
new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val())); 
})
```

That last snippet is for example a great way to get the data structure for use in your question.

The snippet only shows the data structure once, so keep running this snippet every time something changes.

### Debugging trick 2: remove your data

Your whole `hasChild` snippet seems aimed to set up your initial data structure for a user. To aid in testing, I frequently removed the data:

```
new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/myName').remove()
```

And then when you run the fiddle again, you can see what your `hasChild`-using code does.

I often put code to clean out (or otherwise reset) my test data either at the start of my fiddles or simply run a snippet from the browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the techniques! :) I had used push before but it wasn't working so I just tried to set the data. I updated my fiddle however and I'm still faced with the same `Unexpected string` error and I have no idea what it's referring to or why data isn't being sent to the db (I previously reset it by the way so it is `null` at the moment). Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rx4zgLzs/1/ (I did not need the welcome message, but thanks for clarifying that).

Comment: The trick to finding a syntax error like that is commenting out blocks of code. If the message persists, the error is not in that code and your try another block. I localized it to this line: `$('#messagesDiv').prepend(message.text ": " + message.name);`, but will leave it to you to find the actual problem in there.

Comment: Ok I see the problem can't believe I missed that, thanks again, you've been a great help! I'll start commenting out from now on and using the debugging tricks before I post, sorry about that. :)

Comment: now how would I get all the messages to display from every user? Like a global chat (even if the username was changed). Would I need to make a query and the order by child?

Comment: You're aiming incredibly broad there. StackOverflow is not the best medium to help you build an entire chat application. If you want to see a good example of a chat application on Firebase, have a look at Firechat.